# Retrieve sample from ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I have an ArrayList with 100 letters, and I need to randomly retrieve 40 of them only.

Is this possible?
At the moment, I am getting 100 letters each time:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    List<Integer> lettersArray = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(letters));
    Collections.shuffle(lettersArray);
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setImageResource(lettersArray.get(position)); 
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    return imageView;
}
```

I tried this but no change:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
      List<Integer> lettersArray = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(letters));
      for (int i = 0; i < lettersArray.size(); i++) {
        Collections.shuffle(lettersArray);
        lettersArray.get(40);
        imageView.setImageResource(lettersArray.get(position));
    }
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    return imageView;
}
```

Comment: Do you need to retrieve `40` different elements or you need to retrieve the element present at index `40`?

Comment: 40 different elements, thanks

Comment: With or without duplicates?

Comment: Without duplicates, cheers

Comment: Your current code shuffles and gets `lettersArray.get(position)` for `lettersArray.size()` times, so why did you think that would 40 different unique elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> At the moment, I am getting 100 letters each time:

That's because `getItemCount()` of your adapter is returning `lettersArray.length`, which is always 100, apparently.

You need to give the shuffled subset of the array to the adapter before `getView` is ever called.

```
List<Integer> allLetters = new ArrayList<Integer>();
// add some data
Collections.shuffle(allLetters);

List<Integer> someLetters = allLetters.subList(0, 40);
// Remove duplicates if you want
adapter = new YourAdapter(context, someLetters);
```

---

Then you don't care about an arraylist in your getView method...

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    imageView.setImageResource(getItem(position));
    return imageView;
}
```

Comment: Putting up code is hard with just a mobile phone. Glad you put up such a nice answer.

Answer (score 4):

Simple: if you want 40 random entries - shuffle your array (once is enough) and then loop from 0 to 39 and pick the corresponding array slots.

That is all there is to this.

Comment: Short and effective. These are better answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate `40` random numbers and store the results in `Set` to prevent duplicates, e.g.:

```
List<Integer> letters = new ArrayList<>();
Set<Integer> elements = new HashSet<>();
Random random = new Random();
do{
    Integer randomIndex = random.nextInt(letters.size());
    elements.add(letters.get(randomIndex));
}while(elements.size() < 40);
```

If you want the list as a result, you can convert the `Set` into `List`, e.g.:

```
List<Integer> uniqueList = new ArrayList<>(elements);
```

Answer (score 1):

@GhostChat is answer is right but if you don't want 0-40 straight value you can use this

```
import java.util.Random;

Random rand = new Random();

for(int i =0 ; i<40;i++)
    {
        int n = rand.nextInt(40);
    }

//this will generate 40 random values
```

Comment: This solution has a limitation. You could retrieve multiple times the same element in your loop. Which is undesirable as the OP wants unique generated values.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    List<Character> fullList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(letters));
    Collections.shuffle(fullList);
    List<Character> cuttedList = fullList.subList(0, min(fullList.size(), 40));
    //... cuttedList contains 40 elements or less if fullList will contain less than 40 elements
}
```